# Qt vs Boost filesystem recursive file count

Tags: c++, qt, boost, boost-filesystem

```
void countFiles() {   
  QString root_path("C:\\");

  QTime timer;
  timer.start();

  std::uint64_t count = 0;
  std::queue<QString> qt_dirs;
  qt_dirs.push(root_path);

  while (!qt_dirs.empty()) {
    auto dir_path = qt_dirs.front();
    qt_dirs.pop();

    QDir dir(dir_path);

    count += dir.entryList(QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot).size();

    for (auto &sub_dir_path : dir.entryList(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoSymLinks | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot)) {
      qt_dirs.push(dir.filePath(sub_dir_path));
    }
  }

  qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "found" << count << "entries, and it took" << timer.elapsed() << "ms";

  timer.start();
  count = 0;

  std::queue<boost::filesystem::path> dirs;
  dirs.push(root_path.toStdString());

  while (!dirs.empty()) {
    auto dir_path = dirs.front();
    dirs.pop();

    try {
      auto iterator_range = boost::make_iterator_range(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(dir_path), {});

      for (auto &entry : iterator_range) {

        auto entry_status = entry.status();

        if (boost::filesystem::is_symlink(entry_status)) continue;
        if (boost::filesystem::is_directory(entry_status)) dirs.push(entry.path());

        ++count;
      }
    } catch(boost::filesystem::filesystem_error &fe) {
      continue;
    }
  }

  qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "found" << count << "entries, and it took" << timer.elapsed() << "ms";
}
```

Can someone explain to me, or at least give me a hint, why these 2 blocks return completely different counts of files? They both should only count directories and files, skip any symlinks. But still, on Windows this differs by around 20%

```
void VolumeFileTreeModel::countFiles() found 502780 entries, and it took 97549 ms
void VolumeFileTreeModel::countFiles() found 622208 entries, and it took 17022 ms
```

Comment: Add some print statements to print out the files and directories that are being counted, and diff the output.

Comment: Could the person that downvoted, also explain what is wrong with the question? .. And thank you, I will try to diff the outputs

Answer (score 0):

<s>One notable difference is the `QDir::NoDotAndDotDot` filter. Can you try and modify the Boost version to skip these directories as well (I guess comparing the directory name to `..` and `.` should be fine? Since now I guess they will be counted in by Boost and not by Qt.</s>

**Update**

I'll have a second try - how about adding Qt filters `QDir::Hidden` and `QDir::System`? As I understand from [this] question at least hidden files are included in Boost.

Comment: The boost documentation at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_iterator says *"Directory iteration shall not yield directory entries for the current (dot) and parent (dot dot) directories."*  (And the code would surely have never terminated if it did.)

Comment: Yeah I thought that it should trigger an infinite recursion:) I will remove the answer since it's useless.

Comment: @RichieHindle since the question makes me curious I'll try one more suggestion:D